# AngularJS Yeoman + Grunt Build Script1014 Invalid Character IE9

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-9, gruntjs, yeoman, minify

I'm getting this error when building an AngularJS project (testing with default grunt uglification and minification settings) in IE 9:

Script1014: Invalid Character

Across two different projects, the line and character always indicates the character immediately following the colon in the first

```
:"A",
```

in the minified/uglified vendor javascript.

[image: Ie9InvalidCharacter]

bower.json dependencies:

`"dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.2.6",
    "json3": "~3.2.6",
    "es5-shim": "~2.1.0",
    "jquery": "~1.10.2",
    "bootstrap": "~3.0.3",
    "angular-resource": "1.2.6",
    "angular-cookies": "1.2.6",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.2.6",
    "angular-route": "1.2.6",
    "moment": "~2.5.0",
    "ngInfiniteScroll": "1.0.0",
    "angular-ui": "~0.4.0",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.10.0",
    "components-font-awesome": "~4.0.3",
    "select2": "~3.4.5",
    "angular-animate": "1.2.6"
  },`

index.html vendor js:

```
<!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ngInfiniteScroll/ng-infinite-scroll.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/select2/select2.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui/build/angular-ui.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Any idea what might be causing the issue or the best way to debug this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you paste what scripts you're including in index.html in the vendors.js block? And if you already know which file this error is coming from, please let us know that as well.

Comment: @Stephen thanks, updated to include bower.json and the vendor js dependencies in index.html. I'll try to dig into it and find out which vendor .js file might be the source of the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a result of known problems with unicode support in IE.

To avoid this issue, you can pass the `ascii_only: true` option to the uglify task in your Gruntfile.js. The complete uglify section could look like this:

```
uglify: {
  options: {
    beautify: {
      ascii_only: true,
      quote_keys: true,
      beautify: false
    },
    preserveComments: false,
    compress: false,
    mangle: false
  },
  dist: {
    files: {
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For more info on these options see the [UglifyJS API docs](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/blob/master/README.org#api).

Comment: you sir, are amazing. Thank you so much! Any pointers on where I can read up about other effects of ascii_only?

Comment: I have added a link to the API docs. Also see the source at https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/blob/2bc1d02363db3798d5df41fb5059a19edca9b7eb/lib/process.js#L1463-L1491

Comment: Just sending it ascii_only: true didn't help for me. I needed quote_keys: true as well. Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime IE doesn't like when you run your website without HTTP server and can cause this error. Are you running any webserver or opening the HTML directly in the browser?

If running without a webserver, could you try run it in a web server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @roshiro! I'm using Apache which I don't know a whole lot about but I'm assuming this is an HTTP server

Comment: Yes, Apache is your web server. Okay, so your problem is not what I was thinking initially.